# Should the visited/unvisited link colors be swapped?

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed, design, links

The links to related questions on the right of question pages have visited links as a dark color, and unvisited links as a light color. See sample:

[image: related-photo] - the light ones (1 and 3) are unvisited

This is confusing since it makes the visited links stand out compared to unvisited, rather than the other way around. Most other SE sites use a darker (or more distinct from the background) color for unvisited, for example Programmers:

[image: related-programmers] - the dark ones (1-3) are unvisited

and Cooking:

[image: related-cooking] - the dark ones (2-6) are unvisited

Comment: For us color blind folks, the cooking one is at least the only one I can personally see well.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is just because of really high jpeg compression, but I can hardly see any difference between any of those links. Generally speaking, though, I agree, light-colored links should be visited, and dark should be unvisited.

Comment: That's true too, there isn't a huge difference in the colors. Here visited is #222222 and unvisited is #444444 I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made the unvisited links darker and visited much lighter. the fix will be in the next production build.